# function decoding twitter short url: what if there are several urls?

Tags: python, function, twitter

I am coding a function to decode Twitter short urls in the Twitter stream I have captured:

```
def decode_short_url(x):
    urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', x)
    for short_url in urls:
        try:
            res = urllib.request.urlopen(short_url)
            actual_url = res.geturl()
            return(actual_url)
        except:
            return(short_url)
```

But when I apply it to the tweets which contain several links :

```
tweets['urls'] = tweets['text'].apply(decode_short_url)
```

I don't get all the urls in my new variable tweets.urls, only the first one.
Any idea on how to get all of them?

Thanks!

Comment: You `return` within your `try` and `except`. Try using `yield` to prevent exiting the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return something, that's the end of the function. Instead of returning each URL, add them to a list and then return the list after the loop

:)

Comment: Oooops, obviously... Fridays... thanks for the help!